# how can i fetch data from "multiple" pages using axios and useState-useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I have a url which is
https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/
This api consist of 42 pages and 826 datas.

I want to keep all data in one variable to filter later (and i will use show more button). at the beginnig the interface 20 datas(1 page) will be displayed. then, when the user click on show more button it should should fetch the datas of the next page and be inserted below the existing data. That's the reasons why i want to keep all data in one variable.

[Here is my fetch code with axios]

```
const [characters, setCharacters] = useState({});
  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState({});
  const url = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/';

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        setCharacters(res.data.results);
        setFiltered(res.data.results);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);
```

(however, this code is getting only one page from the api)

Answer (score 0):

To fetch all pages of the API at once, you can use a loop to make multiple requests and then combine the results into a single variable.

Here's an example using axios:

```js
const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);
const url = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/';

useEffect(() => {
  let cancelled = false;

  async function fetchData() {
    const results = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= 42; i++) {
      const res = await axios.get(`${url}?page=${i}`);
      if (!cancelled) {
        results.push(...res.data.results);
      }
    }

    setCharacters(results);
    setFiltered(results);
  }

  fetchData();

  return () => {
    cancelled = true;
  }
}, []);
```

This code makes a request to the API for each page and adds the results to the `results` array. Then, it sets the `characters` and `filtered` state variables to the combined results.

When the user clicks on the "show more" button, you can use the `setFiltered` function to update the `filtered` state variable with the next page of results. You can also use pagination to only show a certain number of results at a time.